# Elastic IP Address is being dissociated after a restart

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have an EC2 Instance with a Public IP associated.

For no reason, after a restart, this association is lost and I have to reassociate.

It doesn't happen for every restart.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of public IP addresses available for Amazon EC2 instances:

- A **Public IP address** that is randomly assigned to an instance from a pool of available addresses. If an instance is **stopped and later started**, it might receive a different public IP address. (Restarting an instance will *not* cause this to happen, so I suspect that you stopped your instance rather than merely restarted it.)
- An **Elastic IP address** that can be allocated to your account. The address can then be **allocated** to an EC2 instance. The IP address is static, so it will not change. However, it can be *reassigned* to a different EC2 instance if desired. It remains associated with the account until it is *released*.

If you are saying that you were using an Elastic IP address, then it should remain associated with the instance until specifically dissociated. It will not dissociate without a specific request. If it is being dissociated, then you could use **AWS CloudTrail** to look for the API call that would have caused this to happen.

Comment: I use Skeddly to Start (7 AM) and Stop (11 PM) Instances.

Comment: I think that the problem is being caused by Skeddly.

Comment: I´ll contact their Support. Thanks.

Comment: Since the instances are being Stopped, then you should assign an Elastic IP address to the instances. That way, their IP address will not change.

Comment: Wrong Skeddly configuration.

Comment: @JoseCavalcanti If this question is unlikely to help other readers, feel free to Delete it.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS EC2, By default the EC2 instances are not assigned with static public IP address.

For that, you will have to generate a Static IP address first and then assign it to your EC2 instance. In this way, even after the restart, it will retain the allocated static IP address.

To do this, Navigate to EC2 service, select 'Elastic IPs' from the left menu. Click on Allocate Elastic IP address. This will generate the static IP address. Now to allocate this to your instance, select the checkbox against the newly generated IP address, and click on Actions and 'Associate Elastic IP address'

Hope this helps :)